# ScrollView setContentSize not making the scrollView larger

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I currently have a `-UIScrollView` and I have a function that adds more information inside the scrollView, however inside the function it recalculates the size of the scrollView and I try to make it bigger but it stays the same.

Basically inside `-viewDidLoad`
it sets the "Default" size of the `-UIScrollView`

```
[self.xboxScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(303, 2890)];
```

After some time the device adds a few other values to the `-UIScrollView`

```
- (void)addAnotherCheat:(NSString *)title :(NSString *)description index:(NSInteger)cheatID {
    int titleLocation = 2744 + (cheatID * 101);
    int titleDescription = 2766 + (cheatID * 101);
    float lengthofscrollViews = 2866 + (cheatID * 101);

        cheat1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, titleLocation, 287, 35)];
        description1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, titleDescription, 287, 71)];
        image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, titleLocation, 306, 91)];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"backggroundcolor.png"];

        [self.xboxScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(303, lengthofscrollViews)];
        [self.xboxScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];


            NSLog(@"Scrollview Size : %f", self.xboxScrollView.contentSize.height);
        [self.xboxScrollView addSubview:image1];
        [self.xboxScrollView addSubview:cheat1];
        [self.xboxScrollView addSubview:description1];
        image1.image = image;
        cheat1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        cheat1.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        description1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        description1.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        description1.numberOfLines = 3;
        [cheat1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"STHeitiTC-Medium" size:19.0f]];
        [description1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"STHeitiTC-Light" size:16.0f]];

        cheat1.text = title;
        description1.text = description;
 }
```

When I Log the size that it's supposed to be it prints out the correct height I want, however it doesn't change the height.

Basically I need a method to make the scrollView larger when I've already set the ContentSize.

Comment: I'm sorry, do you want to make the scrollview itself larger or its scrollable contents?

Comment: Are you sure your code is running on the main thread?

Comment: My scrollView starts at the height of 2890, however once I call the function which does indeed get called I want the scrollview height to be larger. It does get larger but I'm unable to scroll down further than 2890, even though my scrollView is over 3200 in height.

Comment: I want to be able to scroll further down.

Comment: i would get rid of all the code that has nothing to do with setting the content size, and then look at it dbl spaced, you might notice an error you didn't see before

Comment: However, even if I add a button and make it say [self.xboxScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(303, 9001)];, the scrollView doesn't change the scroll size.

Comment: Can it be a case where the cheatId is zero always, causing the same contentSize. Did you check for that?

Comment: Are you sure that scrollview's contentSize height is not equal or greater than its bounds height?